# Is it possible to combine the F-test and t-test to test for differences in both the variance and the mean?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, mean

I would like to test $H_{0} :$ $\mu_{1} = \mu_{2}, \ \sigma_{1}^{2} = \sigma_{2}^{2}$ vs $H_{0} :$ $\mu_{1} \neq \mu_{2}, \ \sigma_{1}^{2} \neq \sigma_{2}^{2}$
Is there a test statistic that would allow me to detect both differences in the mean and differences in the variance? Is there a way that I could possibly combine the $F$ - $test$ and the $t$ - $test$ to derive this test statistic? I am assuming that the population is normally distributed but what if it wasn't?
I am very stuck so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

This problem of detecting a difference in two Normal distributions based on independent random samples from each was solved asymptotically by Pearson and Neyman in 1930 using the **likelihood ratio test**. (Specifically, the alternative hypothesis is that $\mu_1\ne\mu_2$ *or* $\sigma_1^2\ne\sigma_2^2.$  Under the null hypothesis, the likelihood ratio statistic is asymptotically uniform as the sizes of both samples grow large.) In 2012, Zhang, Xu, and Chen provided a tractable expression for the CDF of the likelihood ratio statistic: it is a double integral that they compute numerically.

For other parametric families of distributions the problem can, in principle, be solved with similar techniques.

---

Let the two samples be $(x_i|1\le i\le n)$ from a Normal$(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ distribution and $(y_j|1\le j\le m)$ from a Normal$(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ distribution.  The **likelihood ratio statistic** is

$$\lambda_{n,m} = \frac{s_x^{n/2} s_y^{m/2}}{s^{(n+m)/2}}$$

where

$$s_x = \sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2/n,$$

$$s_y = \sum_{j=1}^m(y_j - \bar{y})^2/m,$$

$$s = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-u)^2 + \sum_{j=1}^m(y_j-u)^2\right)/(n+m)$$

and $\bar{x}, \bar{y},$ and $u$ are the sample means of the $x_i,$ the $y_j,$ and the combined sample, respectively.  The CDF of $\lambda_{n,m}$ is

$$F_{n,m}(\lambda) = 1 - C\iint_D\frac{w_1^{(n-1)/2}w_2^{(m-1)/2}}{\sqrt{1-w_1-w_2}}\frac{dw_1}{w_1}\frac{dw_2}{w_2}$$

with

$$C = \frac{\Gamma(\frac{n+m-1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{m-1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})},$$

$$D = \left\{(w_1,w_2)|w_1\gt 0, w_2\gt 0, w_1+w_2\lt 1, \frac{(n+m)^{(n+m)/2}}{n^{n/2}m^{m/2}}w_1^{n/2}w_2^{m/2}\gt \lambda\right\}.$$

[image: Figure]

*Plot of the CDF of the likelihood ratio statistic $\lambda_{2,2}$.  The curve is calculated using numeric integration at the points $\lambda=0, 1/20, 2/20, \ldots, 1$ while the points are the result of a simulation of $10,000$ pairs of samples.*

---

#### References

Lingyun Zhang, Xinzhong Xu, and Gemai Chen.  *The Exact Likelihood Ratio Test for Equality of Two Normal Populations.*  The American Statistician, August 2012, Vol. 66, No.3 pp 180-184.

E. S. Pearson and J. Neyman, *On the Problem of Two Samples* (1930).  Published in *Joint Statistical Papers* (1967), eds. J. Neyman and E. S. Pearson, Cambridge University Press, pp 99-115.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My understanding of the likelihood ratio test however is that one of the models must be a special case of the other. What exactly does this imply and what if this is not the case?

Comment: The null hypothesis is a special case of the alternative.  The LR theory can be used to justify the usual t and F tests, too.

Comment: I don't mean to sound dim but could you possibly explain how/why the null hypothesis is a special case of the alternative?

Comment: And how can you justify the LRT using the Neyman Pearson lemma?

Comment: This is standard material, explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test) and in most textbooks (*q.v.*). If you like, you can ignore the theory altogether and just accept that it suggests a particular statistic. The theory shows that such tests often have certain desirable properties, such as high power among well-defined classes of tests, indicating further evaluation of this test would be worthwhile. To use it well, you would want to study its power. Absent an efficient way to compute the integrals, the power can still readily be estimated using simulation.

Comment: Would it be possible to test this statistic with two samples in R?

Comment: @Mathlete I updated the figure to show simulated results of the null distribution.  They agree closely with the calculated values.