# Sample mean of random walk

Tags: time-series, convergence

I would like to find out if the sample mean $T^{-1}\sum\limits_{t=1}^T{y_t}$ of the simple random walk $y_t=y_{t-1}+u_t$ with $u_t \sim i.i.d$ $N(0,1)$ diverges or converges? I am looking for a straightforward technical proof.

Theoretically it should diverge as $T$ is less than the claimed rate of convergence $T^{3/2}$, but I couldn't find a technical expression to infer this concisely.

Note the standard case for $T^{-3/2}\sum\limits_{t=1}^T{y_t}\rightarrow^L\sigma\int\limits_{0}^1 W(r)dr \sim N(0,\sigma^2/3)$. With $W(r)$ referring to the Wiener process. Any ideas how to show that $T^{-1}\sum\limits_{t=1}^T{y_t}$ diverges?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From

$$\bar{y}_T = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=1}^T y_t = \frac{T}{T} u_1 + \frac{T-1}{T} u_2 + \cdots + \frac{1}{T}u_T$$

the independence of the $u_i$ implies (along with their unit variance) that

$$\text{Var}(\bar{y}_T) = \left(\frac{T}{T}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{T-1}{T} \right)^2 + \cdots + \left(\frac{1}{T}\right)^2 = \frac{T(1+T)(1+2T)}{6T^2} \gt \frac{T}{3}.$$

Some positive amount of the probability of $\bar{y}_T$ must lie more than $\sqrt{\frac{T}{3}}$ from $\mathbb{E}(\bar{y}_T) = 0$ for otherwise the variance would be less than or equal to $\frac{T}{3}$.  Since $\sqrt{\frac{T}{3}}$ diverges as $T\to\infty$, the sample mean cannot converge (in probability).

Comment: +1 This answer has a succinct clarity to it. I'd like to upvote it twice.

Comment: Without nagging on the quality of the answer and just out of pure curiosity, did you device that one yourself or is this with the help of a book or reference somehwere?

Comment: Fair question.  If I had used a book I [would have cited it](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78156/919).  However, this kind of argument is routine and I have seen similar ones in many places, so it's certainly not original.  Indeed, I had started out intending to apply standard material about covariances of random walks and then invoke Chebyshev's Theorem, but in writing it I realized that none of this was really needed: the key ideas reduced to what you see here.  (And I just erased the last trace of a $O()$ argument that also turned out to be overkill.)

Comment: Well done! Last claim seems logical in your post. Is the reverse also true, that is when the variance converges, the sample mean must converge in probability? (You could have kept O() as technically it is only the leading term that is relevant and thus more concise imho)

Comment: The proof of the last claim is immediate by considering the expectation of $\max(\bar{y}_T, \sqrt{T/3})^2$: if $\bar{y}_T\le \sqrt{T/3}$ almost surely then the variance--which is the expectation of $\bar{y}_T^2$--cannot exceed $T/3$.  Conversely, convergence of the variance does not suffice for convergence in probability unless the variance converges to $0$.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_3 for more about such relationships.  Finally, the $O()$ argument is more complicated than the simple observation that Var$(\bar{y}_T)\gt T/3$.

Comment: Interestingly, when we have the scaling factor $T^{-2/3}$ and using whuber's formal argumentation the variance converges to 1/3. However, we also obatain convergence in probability due to $u_t$ being a martingale difference sequence which then, given more subtle assumptions, suffices for the claim in question.